# Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "0") : attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions

Tags: r

I am very new to R and I am having trouble with this error. This is my data:

```
datekey horseno winner  draw    winodds age
65529   1   0   1   10.34   7
65529   2   0   6   22.15   7
65529   3   0   2   53.13   8
65529   5   0   8   9.71    4
65529   6   0   9   2.74    4
65529   7   1   12  9.92    5
65529   8   0   5   150.81  6
65529   9   0   4   6.58    4
65529   11  0   3   16.19   6
65529   12  0   10  61.64   4
65529   13  0   11  31.03   4
65529   14  0   7   919.51  7
65598   1   1   1   2.65    7
65598   2   0   2   8.62    7
65598   3   0   6   26.3    8
65598   5   0   7   7.58    4
65598   6   0   9   97.64   4
65598   7   0   5   271.17  5
65598   8   0   11  97.64   6
65598   9   0   3   13.96   4
65598   11  0   4   54.56   6
65598   12  0   8   6.34    4
65598   13  0   10  91.23   4
65598   14  0   12  18.74   7


> library(RODBC)
> library(mlogit)
> z<-odbcConnectExcel("C:\\Users\\andrewc\\desktop\\Test4.xls")
> y<-sqlFetch(z,"Sheet2")
> x<-mlogit.data(y,choice="winner",shape="long",id.var="datekey",alt.var="horseno")
> summary(mlogit(winner~winodds+age+draw-1,data=x))
Error in `colnames<-`(`*tmp*`, value = "0") : 
  attempt to set 'colnames' on an object with less than two dimensions
```

Comment: When I run the just the first race data it works fine but when I add the 2nd race I get the error which I don't understand? Any help would be very much appreciated. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

> y<-sqlFetch(z,"Sheet2")
>   x<-mlogit.data(y,choice="winner",shape="long",id.var="datekey",alt.var="horseno")

From memory the function wants x<-mlogit.data(data=y, etc etc) but I don't know how finicky it is.
It also needs y to be a dataframe. What happens when you do str(y)? Importing data from Excel spreadsheets may require careful inspection in R in my experience.